# What is the dual matrix (of a sample covariance matrix)?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, probability-distributions, random-matrices, symplectic-linear-algebra

Let $A$ be a matrix. I am most interested in the real, symmetric case, but for full understanding let's let $A$ be complex. What does it mean for $A^D$ to be the dual matrix of $A$?

Can we interpret it in terms of the SVD of $A=U\Sigma U^T$?

Note: This is not merely the transpose. See 6.1 in http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/1211.2671v4.pdf for an example of this term.

I've included the tags random matrices and probability distributions since that has something to do with the unconventional context in which I found this term used. I do not know to what extent they are relevant.

Comment: I've seen "dual map" but I don't think I've seen dual before the word matrix. But of course, matrices define linear maps and vice-versa in the presence of a basis (which induces a dual basis), so we can use the same concept for a matrix. Just in case, can you provide more context?

Comment: An example is the use of "dual matrix" in this paper: http://arxiv-web3.library.cornell.edu/pdf/1211.2671v4.pdf

Comment: I'm not sure what "dual matrix" means, but googling the term turns up a bunch of stuff like this: Armitage: Dual Matrix (2002)
 Video 90 min  -  Action | Animation | Sci-Fi  -  October 2002 (USA) http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0303678/

Comment: According to the paper, if $S$ is a sample covariance matrix generated by data matrix $X$. Then $S=n^{-1}XX^T$. The dual covariance matrix is given by $S^D=n^{-1}X^TX$.

Answer (score 1):

I have heard about dual matrix (of vector) in Computer Graphics course. It was presented in context of cross product and noted as $A^*$ (A-star).
So it was [conjugate-transpose matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_transpose).
Good explanation is [here](https://courses.edx.org/courses/course-v1:UCSDx+CSE167x+4T2015/discussion/forum/CS184_1x_2012_Fall_L4V3/threads/5687062908ea03fae40006ad).